# HP EliteBook 745 G5 install Ubuntu 18 fail (restart usually fail, sometimes ok)

Tags: 18.04, drivers, system-installation, amd-graphics, amd-processor

[image]

[image]

I tried several ways to install Linux system in my notebook(HP EliteBook 745 G5).

I find my boot install the Linux system is ok, but when I restart the Linux on notebook, I find starting display in the windows like the above two pictures. And then display blank screen. At the same time, I cannot access to the operating system（Linux). But sometimes ok. I try to Ubuntu 18, OpenSUSE, Manjaro, Debian, CentOS, but all to fail. I guess it is my GPU drive's problem. My notebook is AMD Ryzen 7PRO 2700w/Radeon Vega Mobile gfx *8(CPU)and AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 10 Graphics(GPU).

I try to AMD download drive of AMD Pro Vega seriers to install(by Ubuntu 18, CentOS, OpenSUSE, SLED),but Not idea.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but if you add the kernel boot parameter

```
iommu=soft
```

to the kernel command line under grub, you might have more success. I seem to recall I needed to do that to my Thinkpad A485 before I returned it for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these parameters at GRUB:
iommu=soft idle=nowait nomodeset

Also I was disabled Spectre mitigation option in BIOS and all of Power Managemet opotions first.
I was success with that setting and HP Elitebook 745 G5 on Ubuntu 1604.